# Expansion of inverse of $x+\ln x$ at infinity

Tags: real-analysis, asymptotics

Our teacher gave us a while ago this problem:

> For each positive integer $n$ show that there exists a unique positive real $x_n$ such that: $x_n+\ln(x_n)=n$. Give the first $4$ terms of the expansion of $x_n$.

It is not hard to see that: $x_n=n-\ln(n)+o(\ln(n))$ by some simple bounding arguments, however I couldn’t find the last two. It would be easier if there is some way to systematically find expansion of inverse functions at infinity, and that’s my question, how can we find them?

Comment: By rearranging a bit, we have $x_n = W(e^n)$, where $W$ is [Lambert's W function](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Lambert_W_function), a.k.a. the product-logarithm. Series expansions and other asymptotics are described at that link. Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: Experiment with logarithms of logarithms. Keep going. It isn't necessary to go to such generalities as expansions of inverse functions at infinity. Clearly that was not the intention of the problem your teacher gave you.

Comment: @SammyBlack Okay I see, but how does one get such expansions?

Comment: Would you like to find the sum with the general $n$th term or an algorithm to find the next term given the previous one?

Comment: @TymaGaidash The algorithm

Comment: @mathlover The derivation start in the middle of page 347 of [this paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/research/tr/1993/03/W.pdf).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, we will show that for each positive integer $\,n\,$ there exists a unique positive real $\,x_n\,$ such that $\;x_n+\ln x_n=n\;.$

Let $\;f:(0,+\infty)\to\Bbb R\;$ be the function defined as follows

$f(x)=x+\ln x-n\;\;\;$ for any $\;x\in(0,+\infty)\,.$

Since the function $\,f\,$ is continuous on $\,(0,+\infty)\;,$ $\,f(1)=1-n\leqslant0\;$ and $\;f(n)=\ln n\geqslant0\;,\;$ there exists $\,x_n\in[1,n]\,$ such that $\,f(x_n)=0\,.$

Moreover $\,x_n\,$ is the unique solution of the equation $\,f(x)=0\,$ because the function $\,f\,$ is monotonically increasing on $\,(0,+\infty)\,,\,$ indeed $\,f\,$ is differentiable on $\,(0,+\infty)\,$ and $\,f’(x)=1+\frac1x>0\,,\,$ for any $\,x>0\,.$

Consequently, for each positive integer $\,n\,$ there exists a unique positive real $\,x_n\in[1,n]\,$ such that $\;x_n+\ln x_n=n\;.$

Since $\,x_n\in[1,n]\;$ and $\;x_n=n-\ln x_n\,,\,$ for any $\,n\in\Bbb N\,,\,$ it follows that
$\;1-\dfrac{\ln n}n\leqslant\dfrac{x_n}n=1-\dfrac{\ln x_n}n\leqslant1\;$ for any $\,n\in\Bbb N$
and, by applying the Squeeze Theorem, we get that $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{x_n}n=1\;,\;$ hence, $\;x_n\sim n\;$ as $\;n\to\infty\;,$
or equivalently, $\;\,x_n=n+o(n)\,.$

Now we will get the first $\,4\,$ terms of the expansion of $\,x_n\,.$

$\begin{align}x_n&=n\!-\!\ln x_n=n\!-\!\ln\left(n\!-\!\ln x_n\right)=n\!-\!\ln\!\big[n\!-\!\ln\left(n\!-\!\ln x_n\right)\big]\!=\\[3pt]&=n\!-\!\ln\!\big\{n\!-\!\ln\!\big[n\!-\!\ln\!\big(n\!+\!o(n)\big)\big]\big\}\!=\\[3pt]&=n\!-\!\ln\!\big\{n\!-\!\ln\!\big[n\!-\!\ln n\!-\!\ln\!\big(1\!+\!o(1)\big)\big]\big\}\!=\\[3pt]&=n\!-\!\ln\!\big\{n\!-\!\ln\!\big[n\!-\!\ln n\!-\!o(1)\big]\big\}\!=\\[3pt]&=n\!-\!\ln\!\left\{n\!-\!\ln n\!-\!\ln\!\left[1\!-\!\dfrac{\ln n}n\!-\!o\!\left(\!\dfrac1n\!\right)\right]\right\}\!=\\[3pt]&=n\!-\!\ln\!\left\{n\!-\!\ln n\!+\!\dfrac{\ln n}n\!+\!o\!\left(\!\dfrac1n\!\right)\!\right\}\!=\\[3pt]&=n\!-\!\ln n\!-\!\ln\!\left\{1\!-\!\dfrac{\ln n}n\!+\!\dfrac{\ln n}{n^2}\!+\!o\!\left(\!\dfrac1{n^2}\!\right)\!\right\}\!=\\[3pt]&=n\!-\!\ln n\!+\!\dfrac{\ln n}n\!-\!\dfrac{\ln n}{n^2}\!-\!o\!\left(\!\dfrac1{n^2}\!\right)\!+\!\dfrac12\left(\!\dfrac{\ln n}n\!\right)^{\!\!2}\!\!+\!O\!\left(\!\dfrac{\ln^3\!n}{n^3}\!\right)\!=\\[3pt]&=n\!-\!\ln n\!+\!\dfrac{\ln n}n\!-\!\dfrac{\ln n}{n^2}\!+\!\dfrac{\ln^2\!n}{2n^2}\!+\!o\!\left(\!\dfrac1{n^2}\!\right).\end{align}$

So the first $\,4\,$ terms of the expansion of $\,x_n\,$ are :

$x_n=n-\ln n+\dfrac{\ln n}n+\dfrac{\ln^2\!n-2\ln n}{2n^2}+o\!\left(\!\dfrac1{n^2}\!\right).$

Comment: There is a term that grows faster than the last term you kept. For in terms of the Lambert $W$ function, $$
x_n  = W_0 ({\rm e}^n ) \sim n - \ln n + \frac{{\ln n}}{n} + \frac{{\ln ^2 n - 2\ln n}}{{2n^2 }} +  \ldots \,.
$$ (Actually this expansion converges for all $n\ge 1$.)

Comment: @Gary, thank you very much for your valuable contribution. I will correct my answer as soon as I have the time to do it. Unfortunately, I am very busy now.

Comment: @Gary, I have just corrected my answer. Please, tell me if you see other mistakes now.

Comment: @Angelo How do you go from ln(something+o(something)) to ln(something)+o(something)?

Comment: @mathlover, I use Taylor expansion of logarithm. For example, $\;\ln\left[1-\dfrac{\ln n}n+o\left(\dfrac1n\right)\right]=-\dfrac{\ln n}n+o\left(\dfrac1n\right)\,.$

Comment: @Angelo And how do you get the term with square of ln(n)/n and O(something)?

Comment: You have to use Taylor expansion of logarithm:$$\ln(1+x)=x-\dfrac{x^2}2+\dfrac{x^3}3+\ldots$$By substituting $\,x\,$ with $\,-\dfrac{\ln n}n+\dfrac{\ln n}{n^2}+o\!\left(\!\dfrac1{n^2}\!\right)\,$ you get that$$\ln\left\{1\!-\!\dfrac{\ln n}n\!+\!\dfrac{\ln n}{n^2}\!+\!o\!\left(\!\dfrac1{n^2}\!\right)\right\}=-\dfrac{\ln n}n\!+\!\dfrac{\ln n}{n^2}\!+\!o\!\left(\!\dfrac1{n^2}\!\right)-\dfrac12\left[-\dfrac{\ln n}n\!+\!\dfrac{\ln n}{n^2}\!+\!o\!\left(\!\dfrac1{n^2}\!\right)\right]^2\!\!+\dfrac13\left[-\dfrac{\ln n}n\!+\!\dfrac{\ln n}{n^2}\!+\!o\!\left(\!\dfrac1{n^2}\!\right)\right]^3\!\!+\ldots$$

Comment: Moreover,$$\begin{align}\left[-\dfrac{\ln n}n\!+\!\dfrac{\ln n}{n^2}\!+\!o\!\left(\!\dfrac1{n^2}\!\right)\right]^2\!\!&=\left[-\dfrac{\ln n}n\!+\!O\!\left(\!\dfrac{\ln n}{n^2}\!\right)\right]^2=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac{\ln^2\!n}{n^2}\!-\!2O\!\left(\!\dfrac{\ln^2\!n}{n^3}\!\right)\!+\!O\!\left(\!\dfrac{\ln^2\!n}{n^4}\!\right)=\\[3pt]&=\dfrac{\ln^2\!n}{n^2}\!+\!O\!\left(\!\dfrac{\ln^2\!n}{n^3}\!\right),\end{align}$$$$\left[-\dfrac{\ln n}n\!+\!\dfrac{\ln n}{n^2}\!+\!o\!\left(\!\dfrac1{n^2}\!\right)\right]^3\!\!=\left[O\!\left(\!\dfrac{\ln n}n\!\right)\right]^3=O\!\left(\!\dfrac{\ln^3\!n}{n^3}\!\right).$$

Comment: Also take into account that $$O\!\left(\!\dfrac{\ln^2\!n}{n^3}\!\right) +O\!\left(\!\dfrac{\ln^3\!n}{n^3}\!\right)= O\!\left(\!\dfrac{\ln^3\!n}{n^3}\!\right)\;,$$$$-o\!\left(\!\dfrac1{n^2}\!\right)\!+O\!\left(\!\dfrac{\ln^3\!n}{n^3}\!\right)=o\!\left(\!\dfrac1{n^2}\!\right).$$